# How to add arguments to a jq function?

Tags: jq

```
def gather($ary):
  INDEX(.[]; .column) as $dict
  | $ary
  | map( $dict[.] | .value );

.[] | gather(["h1", "h2", "h3"])
```

Given the above jq file, I got the following output. I'd like to make "column" and "value" additional argument to `gather()` so that users can easily change them. Could you show me how to make such scalar as function arguments? Thanks.

```
$ jq -f ./main.jq <<EOF
[
  [
    { "column": "h1", "value": "v1" },
    { "column": "h2", "value": "v2" },
    { "column": "h3", "value": "v3" }
  ],
  [
    { "column": "h1", "value": "v4" },
    { "column": "h2", "value": "v5" },
    { "column": "h3", "value": "v6" }
  ]
]
EOF
[
  "v1",
  "v2",
  "v3"
]
[
  "v4",
  "v5",
  "v6"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments are separated by `;` rather than `,`; note also that, as the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures) says:

> Arguments are passed as filters (functions with no arguments), not as values...

Thus you could define:

```
def gather($ary; column; value):
   ....
```

and invoke it as:

```
def gather(["h1", "h2", "h3"]; .column; .value)
```

See also https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/How-to:-Avoid-Pitfalls#multi-arity-functions-and-commasemi-colon-confusability